# How to get the blocks of rows from DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas

This is the DataFrame `df` that refers to my question:

```
2018-03-04 21:25:19  8.0
2018-03-04 21:26:19  9.0
2018-03-04 21:27:19  9.5
2018-03-04 21:28:19  11.5
2018-03-04 21:29:19  11.9
2018-03-04 21:30:19  12.9
2018-03-04 21:31:19  14.2
2018-03-04 21:32:19  15.2
2018-03-04 21:33:19  15.5
2018-03-04 21:34:19  16.5
2018-03-04 21:35:19  14.8
2018-03-04 21:36:19  13.7
2018-03-04 21:37:19  11.0
2018-03-04 21:38:19  9.9
```

I have this code that retrieves the rows from pandas DataFrame based on a condition. The condition is that the value of column `col1` should be between 10 and 15:

```
lower_bound = 10
upper_bound = 15

s_l=df["col1"].lt(lower_bound)
s_u=df["col1"].gt(upper_bound)

s = s_l | s_u

if (len(s)>0):
    df1=df[~s].copy()
    if df1.empty:
        print(None)
    else:
        s1=df1.groupby(s.cumsum()).date_time.transform(lambda x : x.max()-x.min()).dt.seconds
        print(df1.loc[(s1>1*60)])
else:
    print(None)
```

This function should identify the two blocks of rows that fit the condition:

```
2018-03-04 21:28:19  11.5
2018-03-04 21:29:19  11.9
2018-03-04 21:30:19  12.9
2018-03-04 21:31:19  14.2
```

and

```
2018-03-04 21:35:19  14.8
2018-03-04 21:36:19  13.7
2018-03-04 21:37:19  11.0
```

The problem is that this code merges them in a single block. My final goal is to get the end time in the first block which is `2018-03-04 21:31:19`.
How can I do it?

UPDATE (based on the answer of Quang):

```
df1 = df.copy()
s = df1[col].between(10,15)
if (len(s)>0):
    df1['block'] = (~s).cumsum()
    if df1.empty:
        print("None")
    else:
        new_df = df1[s].reset_index().set_index(['block', 'index'])
        s1 = new_df.groupby('block').date_time.transform(lambda x: x.max()-x.min()).dt.seconds
        print(new_df[s1>min_duration*60].columns) # date_time is among the columns!
        print(new_df[s1>min_duration*60].groupby('block').date_time.last())
```

Error:

> KeyError: 'date_time'

Comment: I'm not sure why it's a problem. Just another comment: `len(s) == 0` is equivalent to `df1.empty` so you don't need to check it twice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
s = df['col1'].between(10,15)
df['block'] = (~s).cumsum()
new_df = df[s].reset_index().set_index(['block', 'index'])
```

output:

```
+-------+-------+---------------------+------+
|       |       |        date         | col1 |
+-------+-------+---------------------+------+
| block | index |                     |      |
+-------+-------+---------------------+------+
| 3     | 3     | 2018-03-04 21:28:19 | 11.5 |
|       | 4     | 2018-03-04 21:29:19 | 11.9 |
|       | 5     | 2018-03-04 21:30:19 | 12.9 |
|       | 6     | 2018-03-04 21:31:19 | 14.2 |
| 6     | 10    | 2018-03-04 21:35:19 | 14.8 |
|       | 11    | 2018-03-04 21:36:19 | 13.7 |
|       | 12    | 2018-03-04 21:37:19 | 11.0 |
+-------+-------+---------------------+------+
```

You can select blocks spanning more than 60 seconds by:

```
s1 = new_df.groupby('block').date.transform(lambda x: x.max()-x.min()).dt.seconds
new_df[s1>60]
```

In my code, `date` is the name of the timestamp column. Change it to your actual data.

Comment: Thank you. Could you please indicate how I can retrieve the `date` of the end of the first block (`2018-03-04 21:31:19`). I don't want to do it by row id, because it should be flexible.

Comment: `new_df.groupby('block').date.last()` gives you the last date of each block, while `new_df.groupby('block').date.max()` gives you the *latest* date.

Comment: Cool! Thank you!

Comment: One thing. I do not find the condition `(s1>min_duration*60)` in your solution?

Comment: Also, the line `new_df.groupby('block').date.last()` fails saying that there is no column called `date`. I checked that `new_df` actually has the column `date`. Weird

Comment: What is `new_df`. Can you please define it in the answer?

Comment: Ups, indeed `new_df[s1>min_duration*60].date_time.last()` works fine in terms of `date_time`, but it raises `TypeError: last() missing 1 required positional argument: 'offset'`.

Comment: Did you forget `groupby`?

Comment: Could you please take a look at my post where I posted the whole code? I don't understand what's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```py
s = df['col1'].between(10,15)
split_dfs = []
for k,g in  df[s].groupby(df[s].index - np.arange(df[s].shape[0])):
    split_dfs.append(g)
last_value_in_first_block = split_dfs[0].loc[-1]
```